# flask api auth middleware not working with POST method

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a basic flask api in which I have implemented a middleware to check for authorization header (used firebase_admin sdk for authentication). Now it works perfectly for any `GET` request, but doesn't work for an endpoint which is a `POST` request. Below is some relevant code related to my problem:

```py
@app.route('/is_subscribed', methods=['POST'])
@check_auth
def is_subscribed():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user
        try:
            itemId = request.get_json()['item_id']
            
            subscriptions = db. \
                                collection('users'). \
                                document(user['uid']). \
                                get(). \
                                to_dict()['subscriptions']

            if itemId in subscriptions:
                return {
                    'message': 'User is subscribed to this item',
                    'status': 'success',
                    'data': True
                }, 200
        except Exception as e:
            return {
                'message': 'Error checking subscription', 
                'status': 'error'
            }, 400
```

`check_auth` middleware:

```py
def check_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args,**kwargs):
        if not request.headers.get('authorization'):
            return {'message': 'No authorization token provided'}, 400
        try:
            user = auth.verify_id_token(request.headers['authorization'])
            request.user = user
        except:
            return {'message':'Invalid token provided.'}, 400
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap
```

Whenever I hit this endpoint `is_subscribed` I get a `400` request in my server logs:
`127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2022 11:12:09] "POST /is_subscribed HTTP/1.1" 400 -`

I cannot identify what is the exact thing which is causing this, but if I remove this `check_auth` middleware, it works but now the route is unauthenticated and no access to `user` data, defeating the whole purpose...

Can someone provide some insights or any solution?

`EDIT-1`:

Frontend request:

```js
const BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const isSubscribed = async ({
    itemId,
    token,
}: {
    itemId: string;
    token: string;
}) => {
    try {
        const response = await api.post(
            '/is_subscribed',
            {
                item_id: itemId,
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    authorization: `${token}`,
                },
            },
        );
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        showToast('Error checking subscription status', 'error');
        return null;
    }
};
```

The request always executes under `catch`...

Comment: have you set headers in your requests? what i check with your current code there is no error

Comment: @AshkanGolehPour yes, I have updated the question and included my frontend request...

Comment: 'Authorization':`\`${token}\``

Comment: @AshkanGolehPour but in check_auth middleware I'm expecting "authorization" not Authorization...

Comment: its modified inside of framework just change it to Autho....